# Filter on the first (min) date

Tags: r, dplyr

My data looks approximately like this:

```
  Snap Date   ID   Stage
1 2014-01-01  A1   One     
2 2014-01-02  A1   One 
3 2014-01-03  A1   One 
4 2014-01-04  A1   Two
5 2014-01-05  A1   Two
6 2014-01-01  B9   One 
7 2014-01-02  B9   One 
8 2014-01-03  B9   Two 
9 2014-01-04  B9   Three
```

How can I filter the entries where `Stage` actually changes and remove everything else in between.

Desired Output:

```
  Snap Date   ID   Stage  
1 2014-01-01  A1   One 
4 2014-01-04  A1   Two
6 2014-01-01  B9   One 
8 2014-01-03  B9   Two 
9 2014-01-04  B9   Three
```

Additionally, how might the solution change if there were multiple columns to filter on?

```
   Snap Date   ID   Stage  Colour
1  2014-01-01  A1   One    Red 
2  2014-01-02  A1   One    Red
3  2014-01-03  A1   One    Green
4  2014-01-04  A1   One    Green
5  2014-01-05  A1   Two    Green
6  2014-01-06  A1   Two    Green
7  2014-01-07  A1   Two    Blue
8  2014-01-08  A1   Two    Blue
9  2014-01-09  A1   Three  Blue
10 2014-01-10  A1   Three  Blue   
11 2014-01-11  A1   Four   Blue
12 2014-01-12  A1   Four   Blue
13 2014-01-13  A1   Four   Blue
14 2014-01-14  A1   Four   Blue
15 2014-01-15  A1   Four   Blue
16 2014-01-04  B9   One    Green
17 2014-01-05  B9   One    Green
18 2014-01-06  B9   Two    Green
19 2014-01-07  B9   Three  Green
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *data.table*s `unique` function and its `by` attribute which you can update at will.

For the original question

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df), by = c("ID", "Stage"))
#    Snap       Date ID Stage
# 1:    1 2014-01-01 A1   One
# 2:    4 2014-01-04 A1   Two
# 3:    6 2014-01-01 B9   One
# 4:    8 2014-01-03 B9   Two
# 5:    9 2014-01-04 B9 Three
```

For the Edit3: Just `color` to the `by` parameter

```
unique(df, by = c("ID", "Stage", "Colour"))
#    Snap       Date ID Stage Colour
# 1:    1 2014-01-01 A1   One    Red
# 2:    3 2014-01-03 A1   One  Green
# 3:    5 2014-01-05 A1   Two  Green
# 4:    7 2014-01-07 A1   Two   Blue
# 5:    9 2014-01-09 A1 Three   Blue
# 6:   11 2014-01-11 A1  Four   Blue
# 7:   16 2014-01-04 B9   One  Green
# 8:   18 2014-01-06 B9   Two  Green
# 9:   19 2014-01-07 B9 Three  Green
```

Additional option is using `which.min` (like you mentioned)

```
df[, .SD[which.min(Date)], .(ID, Stage, Colour)]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df, ID, Stage, Colour)
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, Thanks! distinct() is my new favourite thing.

Answer (score 4):

One more option with dplyr is:

```
DF %>%
  mutate(Snap.Date = as.Date(Snap.Date)) %>%  # make sure the dates are formatted correct
  group_by(ID, Stage, Colour) %>%             # group the data
  slice(which.min(Snap.Date))                 # slice off only those rows with the (first) minimum date per group

#Source: local data frame [9 x 4]
#Groups: ID, Stage, Colour
#
#   Snap.Date ID Stage Colour
#1 2014-01-11 A1  Four   Blue
#2 2014-01-03 A1   One  Green
#3 2014-01-01 A1   One    Red
#4 2014-01-09 A1 Three   Blue
#5 2014-01-07 A1   Two   Blue
#6 2014-01-05 A1   Two  Green
#7 2014-01-04 B9   One  Green
#8 2014-01-07 B9 Three  Green
#9 2014-01-06 B9   Two  Green
```

This approach does not require the data to be sorted in advance.

Comment: I really like the slice() function. I think this will come in hella handy! Thanks!